# Why magento 1.9 not showing newly added categories?

Tags: category

Hi I am very new Magento frame work.
 I just installed magento 1.9.0.1 and I added the new category through catalog menu. But still its not showing the category in front end.

1. Category is under default category
2. Is Active -Yes
3. Display Mode -Static Block Only

These are the setting I have done with new category. After saving this, When I go to the front end its not displaying the category. How do I make the category should appear in front end.

I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories)  for creating category.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the category you created has 'Include in menu' set to yes. Also reindex everything and clear the cache.

Comment: @Marius You mean "Include in Navigation Menu", if I set to yes its appearing. Is it possible to make that categories coming as left side block ??

Comment: That's a totally different question. I think you should ask a new question explaining what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the proper root category selected under *System-->Manage Stores*.  In my case, the proper category **"All Shows"**. I can select it by clicking **Main Website Store** and choosing **"All Shows"**.  If I choose **"Default Category"** as my root category instead, **"All Shows"** and any sub-categories of that root will not show on the navigation menu.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments...
You have to set the flag "Include in Navigation Menu" for a category to `yes` to make it appear in the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you say category is under default category - does this mean it is a sub directory of this? as it needs to be in order to show (not physical below it - it needs to be within it as a sub directory)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.acumensoftwaredesign.com/magento/magento-nav-menu-not-displaying
I have the same issue and followed this link.

Comment: Welcome To SE. Link only answers are not the best. Please include at least parts of what is found at the end of that url in your answer.